# how to play image sequence in loop,reverse order

Tags: iphone

I am using below code

```
    UIImageView* campFireView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 175, 175)];
     // load all the frames of our animation
     campFireView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"a1.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"a2.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"a3.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"a4.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"a5.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"a6.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"a7.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"a8.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"a9.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"a10.png"],
                                     nil];

     // all frames will execute in 1.75 seconds
     campFireView.animationDuration = 0.75;
     // repeat the annimation forever
     campFireView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
     // start animating
     [campFireView startAnimating];
     // add the animation view to the main window 
     [self.view addSubview:campFireView];   //  [campFireView release];
```

this works well for a1 to a10 ,
how can i keep moving in reverse order,So it should animate a1 to a10 to a1 continuously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
campFireView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"a1.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"a2.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"a3.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"a4.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"a5.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"a6.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"a7.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"a8.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"a9.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"a10.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"a9.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"a8.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"a7.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"a6.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"a5.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"a4.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"a3.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"a2.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"a1.png"],
                                nil];
```

Comment: that was so stupid of me...thanks Rushi. that a very simple thing,i should hv think of.